# ShowWindow SW_SHOW won't show hidden window

Tags: .net, vb.net

Imports:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

My pInvoke:

```
<DllImport("User32")>
 Private Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

I'm using

```
Dim window As Integer = otherProcess.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32()
ShowWindow(window , 0)
```

to hide a different process than the one I am working from.
That works perfectly fine, but when I try to show it again by using

```
Dim window As Integer = otherProcess.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32()
ShowWindow(window , 1)
```

then it won't show anymore. I've used numbers up to 11 to try and get the other process back, but it just won't work.

My program is written in VB.NET

Comment: Show your `pinvoke` declaration...Something like `Private Shared Function ShowWindow(.....`

Comment: Added my pinvoke, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, _
ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer) As Integer
Public Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40
Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
```

and then

```
SetWindowPos(dbHwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
```

Comment: Same results as before, thanks for your effort though!